# Why define nth root as supremum of a set?

Tags: real-analysis, radicals

Tao's Analysis I says:

[image]

Why would we do this instead of saying $x^{1/n}$ is a real $y$ such that $y^n=x$?

Comment: I think "supremum" is necessitated by the use of $\leq$ (or maybe vice versa). So why use $\leq$ instead of $=$? The best thought I've come up with is because there are cases where $y^n$ cannot equal $x$. The definition doesn't say, but if $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ then there would be cases where $y^n$ can't equal $x$.

Comment: The definition of $n$th root is done via $y^{n} =x$, but to show the existence of $n$th root of $x$ we use supremum. The definition in your question avoids the problem of justifying that the root exists, but then it has to show that $(x^{1/n})^{n}=x$.

Comment: Because you don't know that there is such a number.  I imagine the very next thing Tao does is prove this newly defined number is such that it is x when raised to the nth power.  If it were up to me I'd make a theorem that such y^n =x exist.  Then I'd define.  Either way works.  But the *entire* point is to show lub will prove roots exist in the first place.  Which we have utterly no reason to assume otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, how do you know that there exists $y$ such that $y^n=x$, or that there is a unique such $y$?  This is not obvious (and in fact such a $y$ is not unique if $n$ is even so you should require $y\geq 0$), and until you have proven this your definition does not necessarily define a specific real number at all.  On the other hand, Tao's definition clearly does define a real number (all you have to verify is that the set you are taking the supremum of is nonempty and bounded above).  So you can refer to $x^{1/n}$ immediately after defining it without doing a lot of work to prove your definition is meaningful, which is convenient.